# CDI definition failure:WELD-001476: Interceptor [class] must be @Dependent

Tags: cdi, weld

I'm trying out the APM [MoSKito](http://www.moskito.org) and been trying to deploy the embedded Web UI that will be mapped to `[context]/mui/*` where the MoSKito interface will be shown.

The problem is that I get the following error when deploying app:

> CDI definition failure:WELD-001476: Interceptor [class
>   net.anotheria.moskito.integration.cdi.CountInterceptor intercepts
>   @Count] must be @Dependent

The interceptors are declared in the `beans.xml`:

```
<interceptors>
    <class>net.anotheria.moskito.integration.cdi.CountInterceptor</class>
    <class>net.anotheria.moskito.integration.cdi.CallInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

But since I'm not able to modify the Maven repositories for this APM, I can't really make These classes use the `@Dependent` annotation so I don't really understand the problem, I would really apreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Please use better tags next time. I retagged (fully!!!) your question

Comment: I don't yet see the problem, just wanted to add that from Moskito perspective, all looks good. The interceptor classes are in fact both `@Dependent` (by default CDI add this annotation if you don't pick any other). Are you doing something special with these interceptors yourself? Like building something on top of them?

Comment: @Siliarus, well not really I've been following step by step guide in the MosKito documentation.

Comment: Been following this guide: http://www.moskito.org/integration.html#section-cdi

Comment: Ok that might explain it :) I suppose you used the same dependencies they have there - e.g. Moskito 2.4.0/2.5.0? Checking code at that release, their interceptors are marked as `@Singleton`, which is indeed incorrect and that is probably why Weld screams at you. It seems this was fixed in version 2.7.0+. Try upgrading and tell me if that helps.

Comment: @Siliarus, that did it! thanks! i had to change the beans.xml interceptor to `net.anotheria.moskito.integration.cdi.count.CountInterceptor` and the monitor class also but it works now. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, let me put that as an answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MoSKito in versions lower than 2.7.0 has the `@Singleton` annotation on their interceptors. That doesn't pass Weld validation (interceptors have to be `@Dependent` beans) and causes the described exception.

The solution is therefore to upgrade the framework to 2.7.0+.As a result of this, an update to `beans.xml` is needed as the package names of interceptors changed as well.